# error when building android sample games in android studio

Tags: android

I downloaded Android sample games and imported them in my Android Studio, however I keep getting following errors:

> Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\soko\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':SkeletonTbmp:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\soko\Downloads\Compressed\android-basic-samples-master\android-basic-samples-master\BasicSamples\SkeletonTbmp\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\soko\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42

Comment: Post `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` match in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: explain further please

Comment: This is not necessary.